# ToolTipping a Drop Down list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, tooltip

I have a drop down list in a GridView. The data inside the drop down list has variable length but the drop down list is of a fixed size. How can a tooltip be displayed over each item without selecting any item from the drop down list?

I have googled but come across samples where the tooltip is displayed over a currently selected item of drop down list. Can anybody in the SO community give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to pressume that this will eventually have to work in IE?

If so, it isn't pretty.  IE6 doesn't support the "title" attribute on OPTION elements.

There is an ugly, but potentially usable workaround listed here on the MSDN Internet Explorer forum threads:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3570987&SiteID=1